# iOS Location Manager background updates stopped in iOS 10

Tags: ios, core-location, background-process, core-bluetooth

I have a fitness app that receives location updates and has been working fine in the background since iOS 4. I just noticed that the location updates now stop when the app moves to the background (switching apps or locking the device) in iOS 10. I haven't found any notices of changes to functionality or background privileges; does anyone know what's happening?

My location setup is pretty basic:

```
if (!self.locationManager) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = TRUE;
}

// request permissions on iOS 8+
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

Then this callback receives updates:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    DLog(@"didUpdateToLocation");
}
```

Everything is good when the app is in the foreground. As soon as it moves to the background, this messages appears in the console:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-353.22.1/EAAccessoryManager.m:__52-[EAAccessoryManager _checkForConnectedAccessories:]_block_invoke-785 ending background task
```

Then updates stop. When I bring the app to the foreground, they resume again.

I'm not directly using `EAAccessoryManager` and can only guess what it is. I am using the `BluetoothLE` framework to receive data from heart rate monitors, but when I disable this functionality (stop instantiating a `BluetoothLE` object) the problem remains.

My UIBackgroundModes were set to `location`, `external-accessory` and `bluetooth-central` because I also have Pebble watch connectivity. I tried adding `bluetooth-peripheral` but that didn't help. I also have `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` set and those are working.

Comment: You don't need external accessory background mode. unless you are using the external accessory framework. Since ios9 you need to set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` which you don't seem to be doing https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates however if you last rebuilt your app before ios9 then the old behaviour was grandfathered in

Comment: That's it! I hadn't updated the app since iOS 8, so I didn't know about the change in iOS 9. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new property was added to `CLLocationManager` in iOS 9 - [`allowsBackgroundUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates).  This property defaults to `false` and must be explicitly set to `true` if you want to receive location updates in the background.

Apps that were built against the iOS 8 SDK received `grandfathered` functionality and continued to receive background updates even without setting this property.

Comment: Now that I know the change actually occurred in iOS 9, I see lots of search results for the problem.